# SQL syntax error

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql

Hello I think im messing up my sql syntax, I cant seem to output firstname and second name to my label in asp.net

Table User has an entry UserID=1 and I would like to output the name of that entry into my label:

```
 {
   OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};     
                                           Server=localhost; 
                                           Database=gymwebsite; 
                                           User=a; 
                                           Password=b;");
   cn.Open();

   OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT (FirstName, SecondName) 
                                        FROM User 
                                       WHERE UserID = 1", cn);
   OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   while (reader.Read()) {
     Name.Text = (reader[1].ToString());
   }
}
```

Comment: You might want to include what results you are getting in your question.

Comment: @Brian: He said he got a syntax error.

Comment: I think he wants name. IE: SELECT FirstName + " " + LastName as 'Name'

Comment: Even for localhost, still not good to post your user & password.  Also, do **NOT** connect as root.  Setup a separate user with appropriate privileges.

Comment: bugger i keep forgetting about that! Everytime I post, stack should implement some kind of obfuscator if some one posts something with password= grrr. But im not to fussed sql will be removed when im done. Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by BoltClock try to remove the parenthesys.

Anyway to output both FirstName and SecondName try to use something like:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Name.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
}
```

Comment: thank you!! worked damm parenthesys :) but your string did the job I needed!

Answer (score 5):

Remove the brackets from the `SELECT` field list:

```
SELECT FirstName, SecondName FROM User WHERE UserID=1
```

Or if you are trying to concatenate both fields into a single string:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', SecondName) FROM User WHERE UserID=1
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want one single string i would use concatenation - in Oracle it looks like this:

```
SELECT FirstName || ' ' || SecondName  as Name
FROM User 
WHERE UserID=1
```

Comment: Looks like they are using MySQL.

Comment: In MySQL it looks like this: `SELECT CONCAT(FirstName,' ',SecondName) FROM User WHERE UserID=1`